# rpy2: Convert FloatVector or Matrix back to a Python array or list?

Tags: python, rpy2

I'm using rpy2 and I have this issue that's bugging me: I know how to convert a Python array or list to a `FloatVector` that R (thanks to rpy2) can handle within Python.

Can the opposite can be done? For example, I have a `FloatVector` or `Matrix` that is an R object. How can I convert it back to a Python array or list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer myself :-). Suppose vector_R is a FloatVector. To convert it back to Python you need to do:

```
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri as rpyn
vector=rpyn.ri2numpy(vector_R)
```

And that's it! "vector" is now a Numpy array.

Comment: A "numpy" array ;-) Python arrays are the stdlib module "array".

Comment: `ri2numpy` no longer exists

Answer (score 12):

This worked like a charm:

```
vector=numpy.asarray(vector_R)
```

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of rpy2, you can simply do this in a direct way:

```py
import numpy as np
array=np.array(vector_R)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri as rpyn
vector=rpyn.ri2py(v)
```

Does it in the new rpy2, where v is the vector

Comment: `ri2py` no longer exists. There is a `rpy2py` now though which might replace it.